# ヘルプセンターの一部でCSSが反映されていない

Tags: バグ, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [トップページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help) のみ、見出しなどのCSSが一部正常に反映されていないように見えます。

見出しは本来なら**太字**になるはずですが、このページのみ「標準」で表示されており少々見づらいです。

なお、モデレータ権限で(一部)ヘルプページの編集が出来るのですが、編集プレビュー時には以下の画像の通り正常に反映されています。

---

**ブラウザでの表示(現状)**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**編集プレビュー時の表示**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]