# ヘルプセンタートップページの見た目改善

Tags: サポート, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンタートップページの記述内容ですが、タイトルと説明文の見た目が区別つけ難くて、読み解くのが大変な気がします。
[日本語版StackOverflow](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help)

トップページの記述が充実しているのは日本語版くらいのようなので、形式的にはどちらが良いとは言えませんが、区切りの分かり難い文章がダラダラと続いているように見えるのは、ヘルプとしては悪い例のように思えます。

HTMLのタグは`h3`と`p`で分かれているので、見た目の区別が付きやすいような装飾をしておけば良いのではないでしょうか？

StackExchange関連ヘルプページ
[英語版StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help)
[ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help)
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/help)
[AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help)

他サイト
[teratail](https://teratail.com/help)
[QA@IT](https://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/about)

ついでに、マルチポストの関連で問われたときに紹介するのがMETAの記事くらいしかないのですが、ヘルプの1項目として明確に気を付けて欲しいことを箇条書きにしたものを目立つところに追記しておいた方が良いと思われます。
[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/26370)
[スタックオーバーフローにおけるマルチポストの扱い](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1766/26370)
[他の質問サービスとのマルチポストについて](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2246/26370)
[マルチポストを指摘するときのコメント](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087/26370)

---

関連記事が示されたので調べてみたら、`stacks.css`というスタイルシートの中で、`font:inherit;`が指定されていて、それが影響しているようです。ブラウザのデフォルトは`h3`で`font-weight:bold;`が指定されているのですが、それを`stacks.css`で上書きして`bold`ではなくなってしまうようです。
単純に`stacks.css`の該当の`font:inherit;`を無効にしたら`h3`は太字になりました。
しかしここを変更するのでは影響範囲が広いのでどうやって対応するかは悩みどころでしょうか。

[image: h3style]

Comment: 関連: [ヘルプセンターの一部でCSSが反映されていない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2957/32986)